# In Sitecore PaaS can we use a custom ARM template in the Marketplace wizard?

Tags: azure

I was doing some initial digging into the Sitecore PaaS version that deploys the XM1 configuration. While doing so, I noticed that there was an 'automation options' link that allowed me to view template details and parameters and there was an upload template option.

If one were to upload a custom Sitecore ARM template (say the XP1 template from Sitecore) would the Marketplace wizard be able to use it to provision? Or can you upload customized XM1 templates?

Comment: As far as I know the Marketplace version of Sitecore is provided with a tested infrastructure and you cannot modify it. If you would like to create a custom ARM template why would you like to use the Marketplace wizard? Why not using the Azure Toolkit?
https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/working_with_sitecore_azure/configuring_sitecore_azure/getting_started_with_sitecore_azure_toolkit

Comment: For sure, I'm looking at the Azure Toolkit as well. I was just wondering if anybody had played with the 'upload ARM template' options and knew what it did... just in case doing anything there causes Judgement Day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marketplace in the end is a very convenient way to execute a vetted, tested, set of ARM templates, provides by vendors like Sitecore.  You don't need marketplace to execute ARM templates, quite on the contrary, you can execute your own customized ARM templates through:

- the cross platform command line interface
- powershell
- or even through the portal, if you go to: https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template - where you can write / paste your own template